# Manual upload to Nexus 2.10 doesn't work

Tags: nexus

I'm migrating from Nexus 1.9 to 2.7 to 2.10 and was able to fix all issues apart from uploading artifacts to Nexus. When I'm selecting the pom.xml file and artifact, UIs shows me the progress bar and never ends. No errors in log files. I checked the permissions and all configurations with the previous version of Nexus, don't see any difference.

By the way it happens only with zip artifacts.

Any ideas, what can be wrong?

Comment: does that happen in all browsers? can you upload an artifact via maven? is the server accessed via https?

Comment: I think you would be better off filing a bug report here: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS/ . Make sure you mention your browser.

Comment: I tried on Safari, Chrome, FireFox - doesn't matter, it is not related to the browser. Server is accessed via https. We don't use maven to upload artefacts. And the issue is registered in Nexus but report system https://support.sonatype.com/requests/6934